# How can i reverse a read-only-list in java?

Tags: java, list, jpa

I'm having a problem reversing a list object that is fetched from a database using jpa.

I'm using `Collections.reverse(myListObject)`.

What I intend to do is to retrieve the list from database, reverse it, then send it to my jsp page.

I get the below error:

```
"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Result lists are read-only."
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Please add the code you already have

Comment: create a copy of the list and reverse the copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the list is coming from JPA, the first approach is to avoid reversing the list in memory, doing it on RDBMS side instead. Change the `ORDER BY` clause of your JPQL if this approach is viable in your situation.

If this cannot be done, for example, because you have no direct control over your JPQL, reverse a copy:

```
List<MyType> rev = new ArrayList<MyType>(myListObject);
Collections.reverse(rev);
```